# Xcode refactor tool - merge two classes

Tags: xcode

My class structure used to look like this:

```
            A
            |
          -----
          |   |
          B   C
              |
            -----
            |   |
            D   E
```

After some simplification and removal of reused code, it now looks like this:

```
            A
            |
            C
            |
          -----
          |   |
          D   E
```

(I deleted 80% of the code in `B` and moved a little of it to C.)

Now, `C` is a subclass of `A`, which is pointless because there are zero instances of `A` that aren't also instances of `C`.

I'm looking for a way to use the Xcode refactoring tool (or some other tool) to:

- Merge these two classes, keeping the name of the subclass (or the superclass)
- Change all references in the code to the name of this new class

I don't see a way to do this without doing it one symbol at a time.

The ideal answer is a minimally complex trip to:

```
            C
            |
          -----
          |   |
          D   E
```

Comment: OMG an "Xcode" question that actually **is** about Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: I don't think there is one.

There is ["Move up"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/RefactorMoveUp/RefactorMoveUp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009975-CH20-SW1) which will move methods and ivars up to a superclass but I reckon Copy-Paste would be faster.

I'd probably combine Move Up / Copy-Paste with a rename of all instances of `C` to `A`